# I can access my dashboard without login. It is working properly in my local server , and one other server as well

Tags: php

I can access my dashboard without login, and when I submit it in localhost or on one of my other hosting it is working good. When I am trying new host, my login page doesn't work. I don't find any error also.

Any suggestion please?

**here my login page code**

```
<?php include '../classes/Adminlogin.php'; ?>




<?php
  $al = new Adminlogin();
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $adminUser = $_POST['adminUser'];
    $adminPass = md5($_POST['adminPass']);

    $loginChk = $al->adminLogin($adminUser,$adminPass);
  }
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Admin Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link href="../vendors/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="login">
    <div>
      <a class="hiddenanchor" id="signup"></a>
      <a class="hiddenanchor" id="signin"></a>

      <div class="login_wrapper">
        <div class="animate form login_form">
          <section class="login_content">

            <form action="" method="post">
              <h1>Help Educare Login</h1>

              <!--Show Message-->
              <span style="color: red; font-size: 18px;">
                <?php
                  if (isset($loginChk)) {
                    echo $loginChk;
                  }
                ?>
              </span>
            <!--Show Message End-->

              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="adminUser" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="adminPass" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <input class="btn btn-default submit" type="submit" value="Login" />

              </div>

              <div class="clearfix"></div>

              <div class="separator">
                <!-- <p class="change_link">New to site?
                  <a href="#signup" class="to_register"> Create Account </a>
                </p>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <br /> -->

                <div>
                  <h1><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> Help Educare</h1>
                  <p>©2018 All Rights Reserved Help Educare.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my admin login class code

```
    <?php
    $filepath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    include ($filepath.'/../lib/Session.php');
    Session::checkLogin();
    include_once ($filepath.'/../lib/Database.php');
    include_once ($filepath.'/../helpers/Format.php');
?>
<?php
    /**
    *  Adminlogin Class
    */
    class Adminlogin {
        private $db; 
        private $fm; 
        public function __construct(){
            $this->db = new Database();
            $this->fm = new Format();
        }

        public function adminLogin($adminUser,$adminPass){
            $adminUser = $this->fm->validation($adminUser);
            $adminPass = $this->fm->validation($adminPass);

            $adminUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $adminUser);
            $adminPass = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $adminPass);

            if (empty($adminUser) || empty($adminPass)) {
                $loginmsg = "Username and Password must not be empty!!";
                return $loginmsg;
            } else{
                $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE adminUser = '$adminUser' AND adminPass = '$adminPass'";
                $result = $this->db->select($query);
                if ($result != false) {
                    $value = $result->fetch_assoc(); 

                    Session::set("adminlogin", true);
                    Session::set("adminId",   $value['adminId']);
                    Session::set("adminUser", $value['adminUser']);
                    Session::set("adminName", $value['adminName']);
                    Session::set("role",      $value['role']);
                    header("Location:dashboard.php");
                } else{
                    $loginmsg = "Username and Password not match !!";
                    return $loginmsg;
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

**here my session class code**

```
    <?php
    /**
    * Session Class
    **/
    class Session{
       public static function init(){
          if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '<')) {
                if (session_id() == '') {
                    session_start();
                }
            } else {
                if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
                    session_start();
                }
            }
       }

       public static function set($key, $val){
          $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
       }

       public static function get($key){
          if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
           return $_SESSION[$key];
          } else {
           return false;
          }
       }

       public static function checkSession(){
          self::init();
          if (self::get("adminlogin") == false) {
           self::destroy();
           header("Location:login.php");
          }
       }

       public static function checkLogin(){
          self::init();
          if (self::get("adminlogin")== true) {
           header("Location:dashboard.php");
          }
       }

       public static function destroy(){
          session_destroy();
          header("Location:login.php");
       }
    }
?>
```

here is my site [url](http://sub1.ristechbd.com/admin/login.php)

Comment: Username and Password not match !! returns to me, is your database not empty?

Comment: can you provide login details. dummy one too is fine. as you mentioned can view dashboard without login too. to avoid this,make sure session is working fine.

Comment: when i put real username and password is not working.. if i give real data it should be go dashboard but its not work.

Comment: i post my session class code please check